# Trouble accessing element from Perl anonymous array

Tags: perl, libsodium

I am trying to use `crypto_box_keypair` from
[`Crypt::Sodium`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::Sodium):

```
my @keyPair = crypto_box_keypair();
```

My understanding (confirmed by `Data::Dumper`) is that `Crypt::Sodium` returns an anonymous array:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'k?@ʵ????$p?-0?3',
          '?1????qRo??;???1?'
        ];
```

But I can't seem to access the individual elements.

```
say scalar @keyPair;
```

Returns 1, despite two elements being clearly shown by `Data::Dumper`?

And

```
$keyPair[1]
```

is `undef`.

Comment: Did you do `Dumper(\@keyPair)` or `Dumper(@keyPair)`?  I suspect you did the latter, in which case `$VAR1` is the first (and only) element of `@keyPair`.

Comment: Your values are accessible as `$keyPair[0][0]` and `$keyPair[0][1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do `Dumper(\@keyPair)` or `Dumper(@keyPair)`?  I suspect you did the latter, in which case `$VAR1` is the first (and only) element of `@keyPair`. If you want to dump an array, pass a reference to it; it's far easier to grasp that way.

Continuing with that assumption, `crypto_box_keypair` appears to return a reference to an array rather than multiple scalars. As such, the usage should be

```
my $keyPair = crypto_box_keypair();
say scalar @$keyPair;
say $keyPair->[0];
say $keyPair->[1];
```

Comment: Dumper(@keyPair) indeed !  Thank you for pointing out and explaining the error or my ways !

Answer (score 6):

If it returns an array reference, you need to use a scalar to store the result, not an array.

```
my $keyPair = crypto_box_keypair();
say scalar @$keyPair;
say $keyPair->[0];
say $keyPair->[1];
```

When you did `my @keyPair=crypto_box_keypair();`, you assigned the whole array reference to the first element of a new array, which is why the size is 1 and you can see the contents when you dump it.

According to the documentation `box_keypair()` (not `crypto_box_keypair()`) does return a list. So in that case

```
my @keyPair = box_keypair();
```

should work fine.

Comment: While that's correct, the documentation says it returns a list.

Comment: `box_keypair`, does. Looks like the OP is using `crypto_box_keypair`, which is undocumented and returns the arrayref. Updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: It's not undocumented. It's [the underlying XS implementation](https://metacpan.org/source/MGREGORO/Crypt-Sodium-0.11/Sodium.xs#L526). The `box_keypair` function which is written in Perl calls `crypto_box_keypair` and [dereferences the the array ref which that returns](https://metacpan.org/source/MGREGORO/Crypt-Sodium-0.11/lib/Crypt/Sodium.pm#L262).

Comment: If you need to look into the underlying implementation to find the definition, rather than reading the documentation, I think that counts as being undocumented. ;)

Comment: It's odd that `crypto_box_keypair` is exported at all. In fact the module exports nearly seventy symbols, most of which are undocumented. I wonder how the OP discovered the `crypto_box_keypair` function at all, as it's visible only in the source code. The "official" access to the function seems to be through `box_keypair`, which just dereferences the result of a call to `crypto_box_keypair` and returns the (two-element) list. I don't understand how a prefix of `crypto_` can indicate that the result is returned by reference. An odd module altogether.

Comment: Can't remember off the top my my head, but I think the `crypto_box_keypair` 'idea' (in my head to use the function) came from the underlying libsodium c library.  It is indeed its a bit of a shame its an "odd" Perl module, but I haven't found much better in terms of Perl cryptography (and libsodium access, or at least access to the sort of functionality in libsodium)

Answer (score 1):

While @Adam Millerchip showed you how to access the elements you want, I am going to comment on the other part of your problem. You say:

> My understanding (confirmed by `Data::Dumper`)

In fact, no such thing was confirmed by `Data::Dumper`. If you want to see what is in `@keyPair`, you must pass a reference to `@keyPair` to `Dumper`. That is, you must use

```
print Dumper \@keypair;
```

instead of

```
print Dumper @keypair; # I suspect you did this
```

If you had passed a reference to `@keyPair`, you would have clearly seen it was an array which contained a single anonymous array.

Instead, by not passing a reference, you passed the elements of `@keyPair` as arguments to `Dumper`. In this case, `@keyPair` has a single element, a reference to an anonymous array with two elements. The output from `Dumper` thus fooled you into thinking `@keyPair` had two elements.

That is, you code is equivalent to:

```
 my @x = (['a', 'b']);
 print Dumper @x;
```

that is the same as `print Dumper $x[0]`. If you want to see what is in `@x`, you must pass a reference to `@x` as in:

```
 print Dumper \@x;
```

Examples:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e "@x=(['a','b']);print Dumper @x"
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b'
        ];
```

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e "@x=(['a','b']);print Dumper $x[0]"
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b'
        ];
```

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e "@x=(['a','b']);print Dumper \@x"
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'a',
            'b'
          ]
        ];
```